# How to fetch values from stdClass Object using foreach

Tags: php

I like to get values from the below array the name of each stdClass object [name] to be printed i tried the code below array but i get only one result please suggest me how to get name of each array.

```
$result array as :

stdClass Object
(
[return] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [mode] => BASIC
                [name] => test
                [state] => NOT_RUNNING
                [trainingMode] => 
                [type] => OUTBOUND
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [mode] => BASIC
                [name] => test1
                [state] => NOT_RUNNING
                [trainingMode] => 
                [type] => OUTBOUND
            )
        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [description] => description
                [mode] => BASIC
                [name] => New Campaign from CRM
                [state] => RUNNING
                [trainingMode] => 
                [type] => OUTBOUND
            )
    )
 )
```

i Tried using this code but able to only one output

```
 $i=0;
 foreach($result as $object){
    echo $object[$i]->name."\n";
    $i=$i+1;
  }
```

Comment: it is unclear from your example if `$result` is the parent object, or if it is the object property `return`, which is an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
foreach($result as $object) {
    foreach ($object as $item) {
        echo $item->name, "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the counter.

```
<?php
foreach($result as $object){
    echo $object->name."\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion the above answer works charming :)